# how to get the number of elements in a 2D array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am working with a 2D array in Perl, and have come across a stumbling block, that I am hoping someone can help me with.

I am reading a file that has x number of lines and y number of columns, this I am placing into a 2D array,

for testing purposes I am trying to print out the contents of the first element(line) in the array using a for loop:

```
        for( $m = 0; $m <= $#fields; $m++)
    {   
        printf "Field [0][$m] = $fields[0][$m]\n";
    }
```

The problem I am running into is that this loops for the entire size of array rather then the length of the 2nd element.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `$#{}` dereference to get the last index of an array reference:

```
for (my $m = 0; $m <= $#{ $fields[0] }; $m++)
```

Comment: "Thank you" on StackOverflow = upvote / accept.